# Sed substitution grouping is appending in OSX rather than the expected sub in Linux

Tags: shell, sed, bsd

I've got three comma separated columns. Last name, First name, social.

I'm trying to capitalize all characters in the last name column using

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\)/\U\1/' foo.file
```

In osx this command is appending a capital U to the beginning of each line, rather than capitalizing the Last name column, but it works as expected on my ubuntu instance.

I cannot figure out why this is happening.

The man page lists a bug "Multibyte characters cannot be used as delimiters with the ''s'' and ''y'' commands. I wasn't sure if / was a multibyte character or not (didn't think that it was), but the same thing happens if I replace the delimiter with 'i'. So this isn't the issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 'h;s/[^,]*,[^,]*,//
     y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/
     H;x;s/[^,]*\n//

' foo.file
```

Answer (score 2):

`\U` is a GNUism, actually inspired from a BSDism since that comes from the equivalent `s` command in the `ex` editor (command-line mode of `vi`).

OS/X `sed` most likely descends from FreeBSDs itself descending from 4.4BSD's `sed`, which was rewritten from scratch following copyright issues with AT&T. In any case, neither BSD nor AT&T `sed` support `\U` in their `s` command.

To convert to uppercase, in `sed` portably, you generally use the `y` command [as already shown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195602).

But here a better approach is probably to use `awk` instead:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{$1 = toupper($1); print}'
```

Comment: All of that Unix wars stuff really set the Unix world back - a lot. As I see it, it began with the unchecked fragmentation of the platform, and ended with it nearly being pulled completely apart. The lesson I take from it is that, while innovation is a good thing in that it brings improvement, without a basic standard a computing ecosystem is doomed to failure. It's why I advocate POSIX - it seems to me the surest way forward the Unix world as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Seems /U and /L just do not work with OSX/BSD sed

along with

```
sed /pattern/,+2d # like `sed '/pattern/{N;N;d;}'`
sed -n 0~3p # like `awk NR%3==0`
sed /pattern/Q # like `awk '/pattern/{exit}1'` or `sed -n '/pattern/,$!p'`
sed 's/\b./\u&/g' # \u converts the next character to uppercase
sed 's/^./\l&/' # \l converts the next character to lowercase
sed -i '1ecat file_to_prepend' file # e executes a shell command
sed -n l0 # 0 disables wrapping
```

Thank you guys. My reputation isn't high enough to upvote yet, but Mike you solved my problem with sed, and I agree with Stephane. Awk seems to be the better choice.

Comment: That's not a hack - that's a character translation. It's not the same as a regular expression - it's like `tr`. That's what the `y///` command does.

Answer (score 0):

The simple task do not require `sed`

```
while IFS=',' read -r first mid last
do
    echo "$first, $mid, ${last^^}"
done < file_with_commas
```

If `bash` version do not support variable expansion you can use `tr`

```
last=$(echo $last | tr [[:lower:]] [[:upper:]])
```

Comment: [It does not require `sed` but requires hundreds/thousands/millions of invocations of the `read` and `echo` command in the slowest shell of all?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) Your second one fails if there are single letter filenames in the current directory of if $last contains blanks or wildcards or starts with -?